# convert PHP code to C#

Tags: c#, php

I have this code,need convert to C#.net..

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit">

<?
if(!empty($_FILES["file"]))
echo file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
?>
```

thanks!

Comment: You really need to find magic "php2ccharp.exe" or (captain obvious to the rescue) you need to learn c#

Comment: something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx

Comment: @zerkms: was I the only one really hoping this was about the general task? :)

Comment: @zerkms There did exist a ASP2PHP tool that I used a while back :)

Comment: Why new users do not understand the purpose of this forum? I have noticed many new uses gets downvotes for their bad questions. You have to take some effort to resolve your question and come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like　↓

```
Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(System.IO.GetTempFileName() + "\\" + "filename");
```